# Generate all combinations of a set/array with specific conditions

Tags: algorithms, arrays, sets

Apologies if this isn't posted in the right stack exchange, but I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that generates a set of sets ('set' as synonymous with 'array') with the following conditions:

- Element values range between 0-11
- Set length is between 1-12
- All sets must begin with 0 ([ 0 ])
- Value of element n must be greater than value of element n-1

I want to generate every possible combination of sets with those conditions. So here's a few examples:

[ 0 ],
[ 0, 1 ],
[ 0, 2 ],
[ 0, 3, 5 ],
[ 0, 8, 9, 11 ]

All the way to:

[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]

The main language I'm using is Javascript, but if you're use to dealing with C/C++/Python examples in those languages work too. Just no ASM or Perl please. :)

Comment: The question is on-topic but not the language :) This site would just be about describing the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k = 11$ in your problem, so we want to generate all sets with values in the range $0$ to $k$ and with between $1$ and $12$ elements. Then you can do the following:

- First generate all sets for $k-1$ (recursively)
- Then, for each set, make *two* copies, one with a $k$ on the end and one without a $k$ on the end.

If you prefer doing it iteratively, here is this described in an iterative fashion (pseudocode):

```
generate_all_subsets(k):
    let sets = [[0]]
    for i from 1 to k:
        for each set in sets:
            add sets + [k] to sets
            # (now there are two copies: sets, and sets + [k],
            #  so the size of 'sets' has doubled)
    return sets
```